# AngularFire routeProvider check if user signed in

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, route-provider

I am trying to check if a firebase `user` already logged in by checking to see if the `user` object exists. However when I refresh the page the firebase function runs async the page loads before firebase has returned the `user` object and the user get's redirected, even though they are technically logged in.

See code below:

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$waitForAuth','ngResource', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $waitForAuth, $ngResource) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignupCtrl'
        })
        .when('/classes', {
                templateUrl: 'views/class_lesson.html',
                controller: 'classLessonCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    "firebaseUser": function($waitForAuth) {

                        //user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                            user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                            if (user){
                                console.log("user signed in");
                                return user;
                            }
                            else {
                                //window.location.replace('/signup');
                                console.log(user);
                                console.log("user not signed in");
                            }
                        });
                        *
                    }
                }

        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

I searched around and found some people using `Promise.all` to wait for the user object to get sorted out, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly. Can I get some advice? Or is there another solution?

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // Do an async task async task and then...
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    });

    if(/* good condition */user!=null (?) {
        resolve('Success!');
    }
    else {
        reject('Failure!');
    }
});

p.then(function() { 
    /* do something with the result */
}).catch(function() {
    /* error :( */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your resolvers to return something. For asynchronous operations, that should be a promise (in Angular, from the `$q` service)

```
resolve: {
  firebaseUser: function($waitForAuth) { // dunno what $waitForAuth is for
    return $q(function(resolve) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(resolve)
      // will resolve with null if not logegd in
    });
  }
}
```